# best result i could gather has been "The toFixed() Method"

Tags: javascript, rounding, tofixed

OS: CentOS7

I run "OpenWebSpider v0.3.0" on my local server (for searching/indexing). ~its working as it should. when i receive the "results", it shows "Relevancy XX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX".I would like to shorten that to only 3 Decimal places; "XX.XXX"..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmavn.png)

I am new here, and to some of this javascript. i think i have found what i need to embed? The **toFixed()Method**, but i cannot determine where exactly, or for that matter **If** that is the best way to accomplish this seemingly simple task.?:)

this is (what i am thinking) is the relevant "code" area.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81dkl.png)

### Being a newbie at this i have tried various areas to edit or just add this: for **(var i = 0; i.toFixed(2); i < results.length; i++)**

to the "code area" that is pictured above (pic 2); (with a lot of variations) all results are none though. so far.

Sorry if my "Question" is Not compliant, i will work on it, i absolutely have the highest respect for stackoverflow, and what it is.. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't add pictures of code, add the actual code text to your question.

Comment: Oh. sorry. note taken. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you just want to print out the number with reduced decimals [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) wil do fine. But notice that it will change your number to a string. One other way to do it would be to use [Math.round ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). In your case to get 3 decimals it would be

`Math.round(your_number * 1000) / 1000`.

And for your loop. `for (var i = 0, i.toFixed(2); i < results.length; i++)` (assuming the first `;` should be a `,`) won't work because `i.toFixed(2)` will not only get executed once at the beginning of your loop, it also gets applied to `i` which is just your loop-counter. You need to apply it like this inside your loop:

`results[i]['relevancy'].toFixed(3)`.

Comment: Thank you, wayneOS. That worked perfectly. :) much appreciated.

Comment: @GarrettKrosschell you're welcome. do you mind accepting my answer then? ;)